# How to write function in css

Tags: css, sass

How to write function in `css`
I know that possible with `SCSS`
For example in [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) you do like this

Is their any way with which i can achieve this in css
I am using php as my language

```
@mixin table-base {
  th {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  td, th {padding: 2px}
}

@mixin left($dist) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: $dist;
}

#data {
  @include left(10px);
  @include table-base;
}
```

Comment: Not in pure CSS. You can with css frameworks like SASS/LESS, or do it serverside with PHP. Doh.. nm :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to write function in css? I know that possible with SCSS; Is their any way with which i can achieve this in css?

The answer is No.

CSS is not a programming language. It does not have functions. It really isn't designed to be used this way at all.

Whatever problem it is that you're trying to solve by wanting to write CSS functions, there is almost certainly a better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in standard CSS, you might want to look at http://lesscss.org/ though

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.
If you meant defining a style
in your css
         .data{
          define css attributes}

Call the above in your html using the class attribute of an element